# Get element by ID from webbrowser and show in label

Tags: c#, getelementbyid

So I a having a issue.. I want to show the text from a webpage, on the label on my Windows Application Form. Here is the "Inspect Element" code:

```
<ul id="userInfoNav">
<li>Rank: <span class="value">Sivilist</span></li>
<li>Bosted: <span class="value">Oslo</span></li>
<li>Gjeng: <span class="value">Ingen</span></li>
<li>Penger: <span id="money_hand" class="value">16,000 kr</span></li>
<li>Kuler: <span class="value">0 stk</span></li>
```

I have tried using:

```
web.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav").InvokeMember("Value", label1.Text);
```

But it doesn't do anything..

The texts can change from time to time also..

Comment: What "value" would you want to return? a `<ul>` tag doesn't have a "value"

Comment: @Jcl I want to return all the "Rank" "Bosted" "Gjeng" "Penger and "Kuler".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the outer text:

```
statsTextBox.Text = web.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav").OuterText;
```

And to check if the ID exist, before executing the code:

```
HtmlElement htmlelement = web.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav");
            if (htmlelement == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                statsTextBox.Text = web.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav").OuterText;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not nearly well expressed, but taken from the comments, there are several things that may be what you want:

1. The complete inner html in `<ul id="userInfoNav">` (notice that since `ul` is an unclosed tag, the contents might be different than what you are expecting):

   ```
   label1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav").innerHtml;
   ```
2. The html on each `<li>`:

   ```
   var elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav");
   foreach (var child in elem.Children.OfType<HtmlElement>())
   {
     label1.Text += child.InnerHtml;  // child.InnerHtml contains the html of    each li
     // You can use child.InnerText which would remove the html tags (<span>)
   }
   ```
3. What you said was what you wanted in the comments (i.e., "Rank" "Bosted" "Gjeng" "Penger and "Kuler"). Code specific for this very case and not general:

   ```
   var elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("userInfoNav");
   foreach (var child in elem.Children.OfType<HtmlElement>())
   {
     label1.Text += child.InnerText.Split(':')[0]);  
   }
   ```

I presume neither of these three is what you want, but this is as much as I can do without you specifying more. At the very least, it should give you an idea of how to access the data