# clicking 17 buttons have the same names and values (except id)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to press these buttons through click event

First Code (id 1)

```html
<td id="UPDown_1">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="upMinus">
<img src="/alpha/images/up/minus.png" width="14px" alt="all"></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="DownPlus">
<img src="/alpha/images/Down/plus.png" width="14px" alt="maximum"></a></td>
```

Second Code (id 2)

```html
<td id="UPDown_2">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="upMinus">
<img src="/alpha/images/up/minus.png" width="14px" alt="all"></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="DownPlus">
<img src="/alpha/images/Down/plus.png" width="14px" alt="maximum"></a></td>
```

I tried this code

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
        If element.GetAttribute("alt") = "all" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

it's worked but of course pressed all the buttons

Comment: Your last sentence is saying that everything is working? These aren't buttons, they are anchor.

Comment: All the buttons are pressed ... I need every one separately
something like
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")
        If element.GetAttribute("id") = "UPDown_1" Then
          element.GetAttribute("alt") = "all" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
            
        End If
    Next

Comment: Maybe if you ask something like: How do I get a list of element inside a specific element. Which there's [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157258/find-specific-data-in-html-with-htmlelementcollection-and-webbrowser) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686488/getting-contents-of-specific-div-element) [about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603164/webbrowser-control-get-element-by-type) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344280/get-element-by-id-from-webbrowser-and-show-in-label) already. Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response I don't have skills with writing codes..so please help if you can

Comment: '  Dim doc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
        Dim col As HtmlElementCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each element As HtmlElement In col
            Dim cls As String = element.GetAttribute("id")
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cls) _
                        OrElse Not cls.Equals("UPDown_1")) Then
               **What will I write here?**
            End If
            Dim childDivs As HtmlElementCollection = element.Children.GetElementsByName("img")
    For Each childElement As HtmlElement In childDivs
        **What will I write here**